# Degree of a smooth map with no fixed points

Tags: algebraic-topology

Suppose $h:\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^1$ is a smooth map with no fixed points. Prove that $\deg h = -1$.

The hint is to consider the map $g:\mathbb{CP}^1\rightarrow\mathbb{CP}^1$, $g([y,z])=[\bar{z},-\bar{y}]$. I managed to show that $\deg g = -1$. But I am not sure how to proceed from here. I don't understand the significance of $h$ having no fixed points.

Comment: Do you know the Lefschetz Fixed Point Theorem?

Comment: Haven’t learned it before

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a hint at a geometric solution. First of all, show that if you interpret $\Bbb CP^1$ as the Riemann sphere, the map $g$ is the antipodal map. Now show that if $h$ has no fixed point, then $h$ and $g$ are homotopic. (Hint: When $P$ and $Q$ are not antipodal points of the sphere, there is a unique shortest great-circle path joining them.)